# Django assign custom default value to Charfield

Tags: django, django-models

I am having some trouble assigning default values to a new object field on Django

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ref_contrato = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=incrementa_contrato(), null=True, blank=True) # Empleado -> Varios contratos
```

I would like to create a custom autoincrement field on ref_contrato, I have the format but cannot call the function to return the value.
I would like to send "self" to the function, there, I would extract the object info, proccess it, and return a new value to be set as ref_contrato.
The function:

```
def incrementa_contrato():
    # do something
    return '' # return new default value for ref_contrato
```

I didn't put the code to do the new value because it is not important.

I just I am having trouble calling this function from ref_contrato -> default.

Which option do you think is better? I tried overriding **init** function, save() (discarded), and this one I showed you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why you "discarded" save, it is the only one that could work.

Comment: Ok @DanielRoseman , I tried, But how do you differentiate between save or update?. Because I tried but when someone consults the object, and save, the ID is incremented

Comment: How do you differenciate between save or update inside the code? Thanks

Comment: Check if the pk is None.

Comment: God you saved me @DanielRoseman Thanks a lot